# python subprocess.call() modifies arguments before passing it to shell-script?

Tags: python, bash, shell, subprocess, amos

I am writing a python wrapper for calling programs of the AMOS package (specifically for merging genome assemblies from different sources using good ol' minimus2 from AMOS).

The scripts should be called like this when using the shell directly:

```
toAmos -s myinput.fasta -o testoutput.afg
minimus2 testoutput -D REFCOUNT=400 -D OVERLAP=500
```

> [*just for clarification:*
>
> *-toAmos:  converts my input.fasta file to .afg format and requires an input sequence argument ("-s") and an output argument ("-o")*
>
> *-minimus2: merges a sequence dataset against reference contigs and requires an argument "-D REFCOUNT=x" for stating the number of rerference seqeunces in your input and an argument "-D OVERLAP=Y" for stating the minimum overlap between sequences*]

So within my script I use subprocess.call() to call the necessary AMOS tools.

Basically I do this:

```
from subprocess import call:
output_basename = "testoutput"
inputfile = "myinput.fasta"

call(["toAmos", "-s " + inputfile, "-o " + output_basename + ".afg"])
call(["minimus2", output_basename, "-D REFCOUNT=400", "-D OVERLAP=500"])
```

But in this case the AMOS tools cannot interpret the arguments anymore. The arguments seem get modified by subprocess.call() and passed incorrectly. The error message I get is:

```
Unknown option: s myinput.fasta
Unknown option: o testoutput.afg
You must specify an output AMOS AFG file with option -o
/home/jov14/tools/miniconda2/bin/runAmos: unrecognized option '-D REFCOUNT=400'
Command line parsing failed, use -h option for usage info
```

It seems that the arguments get passed without the leading "-"? So I then tried passing the command as a single string (including arguments) like this:

```
call(["toAmos -s " + inputfile +" -o " + output_basename + ".afg"])
```

But then I get this error...

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

... presumably because subprocess.call is interpreting the whole string as the name for a single script.
I guess I COULD probably try `shell=True` as a workaround, but the internet is FULL of instructions clearly advising against this.

What seems to be the problem here?
What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### answer

Either do:

```
call("toAmos -s " + inputfile +" -o " + output_basename + ".afg") # single string
```

or do:

```
call(["toAmos", "-s", inputfile, "-o", output_basename + ".afg"]) # list of arguments
```

#### discussion

In the case of your:

```
call(["toAmos", "-s " + inputfile, "-o " + output_basename + ".afg"])
```

you should supply:

- either `"-s" + inputfile` (no space after `-s`), `"-o" + output_basename + ".afg"`
- or `"-s", inputfile` (separate arguments), `"-o", output_basename + ".afg"`

In the case of your:

```
call(["minimus2", output_basename, "-D REFCOUNT=400", "-D OVERLAP=500"])
```

the `"-D REFCOUNT=400"` and `"-D OVERLAP=500"` should be provided as two items each (`'-D', 'REFCOUNT=400', '-D', 'OVERLAP=500'`), or drop the spaces (`'-DREFCOUNT=400', '-DOVERLAP=500'`).

#### additional info

You seem to lack knowledge of how a shell splits a command-line; I suggest you always use the single string method, unless there are spaces in filenames or you have to use the `shell=False` option; in that case, I suggest you always supply a list of arguments.

Comment: The first option did nor work for me (see "no such file" error at end of post above). But the second option is a great help. I did not realize you had to pass the argument flag and respective argument separately. Thanks

Comment: AH, ok. Sorry, just realized that you passed the string NOT as a list. Somehow I had gathered from examples, that subprocess.call() ONLY accepted lists, and a simple command without arguments would have to be called as a list with only one item. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

`-s` and following input file name should be separate arguments to `call`, as they are in the command line:

```
call(["toAmos", "-s", inputfile, "-o", output_basename + ".afg"])
```

Comment: Ah, ok. I have to pass all flags and respective argument strings separately! I thought I had to pass each flag together with it's respective argument. Silly of me. Thanks!

Comment: You typicall **can** pass each flag with its respective argument, if you do **not** add a space after the option letter. Option-parsing libraries typically expect either a single command-line argument `"-oOPTION_ARGUMENT"` or two command-line arguments `"-o", "OPTION_ARGUMENT"`. This is what the shell supplies upon command invocation, and so should you supply. Adding a space between option letter and option argument is like typing `'grep' '-F' '-e your_pattern'` in the shell; it's not what it's expected and it won't work.